# save() got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to use the save method from django forms. I'm passing 2 other parameters into save - user id and product id, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
TypeError at /kinect-xbox-360/review_submit/
save() got multiple values for keyword argument 'uid'
```

This is my save method:

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Review        
                fields = ('review_text','tag')

        tag = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'teste'}), label='Descreva este produto em 1 palavra', help_text = 'separe as palavras por vírgulas')
        review_text = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':150,'rows':5}), label='O que você achou deste produto?', min_length=50, max_length=2000)

    def save(uid, product, self, commit=True):
            # save the response object
            response = super(ReviewForm, self).save(commit=False)
            #print(self.cleaned_data['review_text'])
            #response.survey = self.survey
            #user = uid
            tag = self.cleaned_data['tag']
            product = product
            review_text = self.cleaned_data['review_text']
            #created
            #updated 


            response.save()

            return response
```

And this is the view that deals with POST response:

```
u = User.objects.get(username=reviews.user)
prod = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
if request.method=="POST":
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save(uid=u.id, product=prod.id)
            msg = 'Obrigado por avaliar ' + prod.name
        else:
            msg = 'Houve algum erro no servidor :('
        return render(request, 'product_detail.html', {'prod':prod, 'reviews':reviews, 'user':u.first_name, 'msg':msg})    
    else:    
        form = ReviewForm()    
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', {'prod':prod, 'reviews':reviews, 'user':u.first_name, 'form':form})
```

Comment: Just a question, why `self` is not the first parameter in `save`?

Comment: Because I'm using specific parameters - uid and product - that are not usual for save. If I put these two on the end, django returns an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paulo is on the right track in the comments. `self` has to be the first argument in a method definition. You can't arbitrarily reorder arguments like that.